Selectively calling test functions with capsys
I can selectively run test_function_1, overriding instrumentation from my conftest.py fixtures1
def test_function_1(instrumentation: dict[str, float]) -> None:
    assert instrumentation['a'] > instrumentation['b']

def test_function_2(capsys) -> None:
    print("Hello, pytest!")
    captured = capsys.readouterr()
    assert captured.out == "Hello, pytest!\n"

when I try to call test_function_2, I don't know how to pass capsys to it2 :
import tests
import pytest # <--- doesn't help ...

def test_callee_with_instrumentation():
    tests.test_function_1({'a': 110, 'b': 55, 'g': 6000})

def test_callee_with_capsys():
    # tests.test_function_2()              # <--- TypeError: test_function_2() missing 1 required positional argument: 'capsys'
    # tests.test_function_2(capsys)        # <--- NameError: name 'capsys' is not defined 
    # tests.test_function_2(pytest.capsys) # <--- AttributeError: module 'pytest' has no attribute 'capsys'
    pass

test_callee_with_instrumentation()
test_callee_with_capsys()

I'm pretty sure the conftest.py fixtures are irrelevant, but for completeness:
import pytest

@pytest.fixture(scope='function')
def instrumentation():
    return { 'a': 800, 'b': 620, 'c': 44 }


1 In my real code, the capsys is one of many parameters.
2 A similar question exists here. It is not a duplicate IMHO, because I'm asking about programmatically running tests, and not about the proper meaning of capsys.

Why not define test_callee_with_capsys with capsys as a parameter, just like test_function2? Then it's available to pass to test_function2 when you call it explicitly, rather than needing pytest provide it.

but at some point, I'll have to provide capsys ... and I don't have any clue where it's coming from. ...

It's coming from the code that actually calls test_callee_with_capsys. Don't call it explicitly; let the test framework call it with the necessary fixture as an argument.

capsys is a PyTest fixture.
You can list all the fixtures using:
pytest --fixtures

The source code is found in _pytest/capture.py. (Note: You should not try to directly instantiate/call the fixture.)
Write your function with an argument:
import tests

def test_callee_with_instrumentation():
    tests.test_function_1({'a': 110, 'b': 55, 'g': 6000})

def test_callee_with_capsys(capsys):
    tests.test_function_2(capsys)

Then run pytest your_test_file.py and PyTest will automatically instantiate the fixture and pass it into the test.

If you don't want to use PyTest to run the tests then don't use capsys to try to capture the standard output.
from contextlib import redirect_stdout
from io import StringIO

def test_function_1(instrumentation) -> None:
    assert instrumentation['a'] > instrumentation['b']

def test_function_2() -> None:
    with redirect_stdout(StringIO()) as f:
        print("Hello, pytest!")
    captured = f.getvalue()
    assert captured == "Hello, pytest!\n"



If you do want to use PyTest but don't want to directly call PyTest from the console then call pytest.main() from within your code:
import tests

def test_callee_with_instrumentation():
    tests.test_function_1({'a': 110, 'b': 55, 'g': 6000})

def test_callee_with_output(capsys):
    tests.test_function_2(capsys)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import pytest
    pytest.main()


the problem is I don't call pytest, I call python ( it's a databricks notebook )

@OrenIshShalom Either don't use PyTest fixtures (which means don't use capsys and check for the output another way) or use PyTest fixtures (which means either using pytest or python -m pytest from the command line or use pytest.main() in your code).

I tweaked the arguments sent to pytest.main so it can work from any file calling the tests. In addition, added focus for a single test ( in case users want to selectively run a single test ). I'm posting as a new answer because I don't like to edit other people's answers ( Feel free to merge, if you think it's better - i'll then remove my answer )

If one wants to selectively run only some tests, and if the underlying file has any arbitrary name, the following tweaks in pytest.main arguments may be of help:
import tests
import pytest

def test_callee_with_instrumentation():
    tests.test_function_1({'a': 110, 'b': 55, 'g': 6000})

def test_callee_with_capsys(capsys):
    tests.test_function_2(capsys)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import pytest
    pytest.main([
        '-k',
        'callee_with_capsys', # <--- selectively run just a single test
        '--override-ini',
        f'python_files={__file__}' # <--- collect just this file !
    ])

Then when you run the script with python ( not pytest ):
(BBB) orenishshalom BBB % python main.py 
=============================================================== test session starts ================================================================
platform darwin -- Python 3.13.0, pytest-8.3.3, pluggy-1.5.0
rootdir: /Users/orenishshalom/Downloads/BBB
collected 2 items / 1 deselected / 1 selected                                                                                                      

main.py .                                                                                                                                    [100%]

========================================================= 1 passed, 1 deselected in 0.01s ==========================================================


1 Coming from a databricks context, I still have a hard time since __file__ is not defined when running a cell ... arrggghh ...
